# Steam? Ubuntu 12.04? Windows? Wine? Play onLinux?

Tags: wine, configuration, steam, playonlinux

ok i have playonlinux downloaded and steam downloaded as well. i bought a windows game from the steam store and im trying to create a virtual disk to install and play? can anyone assist me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open PlayOnLinux and click install, then click the link to installing a non-listed program or game. Then find the steam file as the source for the install.

Alternatively, find the executable steam program, right click and open with PlayOnLinux or Wine Windows Program Loader.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience if you install Steam on playonlinux and purchase/install a game you should be able to run the game through Steam without much of a problem. That is the game should be able to be launched through the Steam interface without any extra steps.

Now whether or not the game works perfectly (or even runs at all) may or may not be the case. That depends on the game requirements among other things.

Keep in mind that there is also a native Linux version of Steam available (although you will only be able to play games that are supported with Linux - there are many available and more coming all the time).

Here is a link to the Steam site that tells you how to install Steam on Linux as well as how to install Steam on playforlinux:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux